# Replace a word between an html tag

Tags: php, regex, replace

I am trying to get texts between two symbols or HTML tags, then find and replace all the words 'sun' with 'moon' within that HTML tag or `<` with `&lt;`. for example I have a `$text` like below:

```
<body>
    <p>
    text text sun text text...
       <tag> some text here sun some text here </tag>
    text text sun text sun text...
       <span>
           <tag> text here sun text text sun text </tag>
           <tag> sun text here sun text sun, sun </tag>
       </span>
    </p>
</body>
```

I would like to find all the `sun`'s between the `<tag>...</tag>` tags and replace them with `moon` so that the result will be:

```
<body>
    <p>
    text text sun text text...
       <tag> some text here moon some text here </tag>
    text text sun text sun text...
       <span>
           <tag> text here moon text text moon text </tag>
           <tag> moon text here moon text moon, moon </tag>
       </span>
    </p>
</body>
```

I tried `$text = str_replace("sun","moon",$text);` but this will replace all the matches in or out of the tags. Also tried `preg_replace("/(<tag>)(.*?)sun(.*?)(<\/tag>)/", "$2 moon $3", $text);` it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: You should look into PHP's [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for parsing HTML. Don't use regular expressions, since it's not suited for unregular content like HTML. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: [Try with `preg_replace_callback`](https://www.phprun.org/M8vpHR). But better to use a HTML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably be done by use of a HTML parser as mentioned in comments. If you want to uses regex, I'd use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) (use of [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) >= PHP 5.3).

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('~<tag>\K.*?(?=</tag>)~s', function ($m) {
  return preg_replace(['~\bsun\b~i','~<~','~>~'], ["moon","&lt;","&rt;"], $m[0]);
}, $text);
```

[See PHP demo at PhpRun.org](https://www.phprun.org/rrbkn8) - without anonymous function:

```
function rep_tag ($m) {
  return preg_replace(['~\bsun\b~i','~<~','~>~'], ["moon","&lt;","&rt;"], $m[0]);
}

$text = preg_replace_callback('~<tag>\K.*?(?=</tag>)~s', 'rep_tag', $text);
```

[Regex demo and explanation at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OEXZZ7/1)

Answer (score 2):

If the text inside the tags doesn't contain any `<`s, one option is to search for `sun`, followed by lookahead for non-`<` characters, followed by `<\/tag>`:

```
$str = "<body>
    <p>
    text text sun text text...
       <tag> some text here sun some text here </tag>
    text text sun text sun text...
       <span>
           <tag> text here sun text text sun text </tag>
           <tag> sun text here sun text sun, sun </tag>
       </span>
    </p>
</body>";
$result = preg_replace("/sun(?=[^<]*<\/tag>)/", "moon", $str);
```

Output:

```
<body>
    <p>
    text text sun text text...
       <tag> some text here moon some text here </tag>
    text text sun text sun text...
       <span>
           <tag> text here moon text text moon text </tag>
           <tag> moon text here moon text moon, moon </tag>
       </span>
    </p>
</body>
```

That said, using regular expressions to parse HTML is not recommended except in the most trivial cases - consider using a proper HTML parser instead, if at all possible.

Comment: Thank you. But I also want to replace `<` between that tag with `&lt;`!

Comment: This is the first time that's been mentioned - if that's a requirement, please include it in your question itself, thanks

Comment: I didn't know `<` should be mentioned. Question edited. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Search: `(<tag>)(.*?)sun(.*?)(<\/tag>)`

Replace by: `\1moon\4`